# JSLint : how to use it?

Tags: jslint

I've understood that JSLint is a great tool for JavaScript development but I've some dark points in my global comprehension of this.

1. How to use it inside my development environment ? In other words how and when do you run JSLint against your code ? I've seen the Aptana integration but it seems that it doesn't take into account statements like :

   ```
   /* jslint nomen: false */
   ```
2. How to work correctly in a client side development environment ? I want JSLint to feel good when parsing calls including objects like "console", "$" or "JQuery".
3. How to use it on a whole project with multiple files (with no import statement inside of them) ?

I've read to much statement suggesting to copy paste on jslint to sleep correctly, so any answer consisting of configuring the online JSLint form would be considered as irrelevant.

Comment: Which IDE/editor are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry to write this answer which is not really one. The best solution I've found is to use JSHint which is a concurrent to JSLint with some nice extra features :

- Installation is made easy through NPM with command like (also works for JSLint), NPM is required :

  ```
  npm install -g jshint
  ```
- Execution is made easy against a lot of file (doesn't work for JSLint) :

  ```
  jshint mycodedirectory
  ```
- Configuration is possible through the *--config* options, config files look like :

  ```
  {
    "curly":true,
    "eqeqeq": true,
    "immed": true,
    "bitwise": true,
    "newcap": true,
    "noempty": true,
    "unused": true,
    "camelcase":true,
    "undef": true,
    "strict": true,
    "trailing": true,
    "maxparams": 7,
    "maxdepth": 5,
    "maxstatements": 50,
    "maxcomplexity": 13
  }
  ```

This solution works for both browser and server code, it's IDE and OS independent, it can be easily integrated in continuous integration process.

Answer (score 1):

Some one came up with a solution to run it automatically on your project using node.js:

[Automating JSLint Validation](https://web.archive.org/web/20111117163644/https://af-design.com/blog/2011/01/04/automating-jslint-validation/)

Comment: The link in this answer is broken.

Comment: Thanks, after 11 years the website doesn't exist. I'll update to archive.org

Answer (score 0):

I use (a slightly modified) [JSLINT for WSH](http://code.google.com/p/jslint-for-wsh/) on Emacs/WinXP. It highlights problematic code right while I am typing:

- This is of great help not only to enforce the configured coding style, but also to find many JavaScript syntax errors before executing code.
- It does respect statements such as `/* jslint nomen: false */`.
- As you are asking concerning linting code that runs in a browser environment with jQuery, simply use standard JSLint options:

  ```
  /*jslint browser: true */
  /*global $ */
  ```

Just be sure to replace the included JSLint code with the latest version.